# Convert a String to Data in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

I received the following information from an endpoint:

```
[
{
    "number": 348,
    "name": "Roger Alabama",
    "img": "data:image/png;base64,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
```

I was able to decode the JSON information properly, but my problem is to transform the string on "img" that is ""data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAb8AAAG/CAIAAABHcU4lAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U....." into an UIImage.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string)

Comment: Note that there is only [one relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236797/20287183) in that duplicate question.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just found a better duplicate that specifically deals with converting a `data:` URL into a UIImage. See [Base64 string to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674591/base64-string-to-uiimage).